# Golang TCP сервер, утечка соединений?

Tags: сервер, golang, tcp

Написал TCP сервер, который ждет подключения. Первые пару дней сервер работает как часы, спустя пару дней на команде Read возникают ошибки вида

```
read tcp ip_address:port->ip_address2:port2: read: connection reset by peer
```

Думаю, что возможно после работы с клиентом остаются висящие сессии, которые накапливаются. Сам новичек в Go.

```
    package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "encoding/hex"
    "encoding/binary"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    "strconv"
    "time"
    "os"
)
     
func main() {

    sqlT, err := sqlx.Connect("mysql", "mtm:password@tcp(localhost:3306)/mtm")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer sqlT.Close()
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":44444") 
     
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err) 
        return
    } 
    defer listener.Close() 
    fmt.Println("Server is listening...")
    for { 
        conn, err := listener.Accept() 
        if err != nil { 
            fmt.Println(err) 
            conn.Close() 
            continue
        } 
        go handleConnection(conn, sqlT)  // запускаем горутину для обработки клиента
    }

}
// обработка подключения
func handleConnection(conn net.Conn, sqlT *sqlx.DB) {
    defer conn.Close() // Вроде бы тут должно происходить закрытие, когда закончится выполнение функции
    
    g_byte := make([]byte, 2000)

    l, err := conn.Read(g_byte)

    if err !=nil{ 
        fmt.Println(l)
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    
    timeFile := time.Now()

    f, err := os.OpenFile("лог.txt", os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0600)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    if _, err = fmt.Fprintln(f, timeFile.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05") + " " + hex.EncodeToString(g_byte)); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if (g_byte[0] != 0x00){
        inclComm := []byte{0x68, 0x05, 0x00, 0x05, 0x01, 0x0B}  
        conn.Write(inclComm)
    }else{
        inclComm := []byte{0x68, 0x05, 0x00, 0x05, 0x01, 0x0A}
        finalTime := []byte{0x68, 0x05, 0x00, 0x05, 0x01, 0x0B}
        finalTimeTwo := []byte{0x68, 0x05, 0x00, 0x05, 0x01, 0x0c}
        finalTree := []byte{0x68, 0x05, 0x00, 0x05, 0x01, 0x0D}
        
        conn.Write(inclComm)
        
        conn.Write(finalTime)
        
        conn.Write(finalTimeTwo)
        
        conn.Write(finalTree)
    }
}
```

Попробовал изучить работу программы под strace и обнаружил такую ошибку

```
setsockopt(15, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], 4) = 0
futex(0xc420058110, FUTEX_WAKE, 1)      = 1
accept4(5, 0xc420039c10, [112], SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable). <--- Вот она
futex(0x737db0, FUTEX_WAIT, 0, NULL
```

Comment: это скан портов кмк

Answer (score 0):

Почему вы передаёте net.Conn, а не *net.Conn? Вы создаёте тупо копию соединения не подключенную ни к чему.
У вас откровенная утечка сокетов. И поскольку вам система отвечает "Resource temporarily unavailable" -- очевидно, лимит сокетов на ВАШЕЙ системе исчерпан.